# Could you please explain this to me?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

$$(x-c)^2 + y^2 + z^2=3$$

$$x^2+(y-1)^2 + z^2=1$$

Then corresponding normal vectors will be perpendicular , ie when $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$
is on the intersection, then (using the gradient)

$$(x_0-c,y_0,z_0)\cdot (x_0,y_0-1,z_0)=0$$

I am not geting how do they get

$$(x_0-c,y_0,z_0)\cdot(x_0,y_0-1,z_0)=0$$

Please help.Thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are taking the dot product of the gradient and setting it to $0$. When the dot product of two vectors is zero then the vectors are perpendicular.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Do I have to find gradient of these two equations?

Comment: @user114873:Yes.Do you know the formula? (Just partial derivatives of the corresponding terms by x,y,z respectively)

Comment: Yes, but the gradient is already given to you in the question. In general $\nabla f(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}\hat i + \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial y}\hat j + \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial z}\hat k$

Comment: Okay let me do this.

Comment: Now I got it....Thank you so much for your help.